# Trouble filtering an array based on a multi-dimensional array using computed function in Vue

Tags: arrays, vue.js

Using vue I am trying to change/update an array (draggables) based on the logic that if the object exists in another array of arrays (drozones) it will be removed from draggables

Each draggable would only be found in the index of the multi-dimensional array that matches the draggables dropID.

Every approach I have tried either returns all draggable items, no draggable items or the incorrect draggable items is being removed.

```
// In this example I have three droppable and two drop areas, the first drop area can handle two droppable and the last area only one.

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in draggables">Item ID: {{item.id}}  - Dropzone ID: {{item.dropID}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>

data: {
    draggableItems: [{id: 0, dropID: 0 }, {id: 1, dropID: 0 }, {id: 2, dropID: 1 }],
    dropzones: [[{id: 1, dropID: 0 }], []]
},
computed : () {
   draggables () {
     return this.draggableItems.filter((item, index) => {
       console.log('item', item)
    
       return this.dropzones.filter((zone,i)  => {
          if (zone.length === 0) return
          return item.id !== zone[i].id
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bilcker/n9chLofb/317/) of some of my attempts but with no luck yet. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to detect the key for comparing 2 object or you need a function to compare object. You can try [`isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual) function of `lodash` or compare 2 result from JSON.stringify

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    draggableItems: [{id: 0, dropID: 0 }, {id: 1, dropID: 0 }],
    dropzones: [
        [   
        {id: 1, dropID: 0 }
      ], 
      []
     ]
  },
  computed: {
    draggables () {
        return this.draggableItems.filter((item, index) => {
        return !this.dropzones.some((zone,i)  => {
            
          return zone.some(zoneitem => JSON.stringify(item) === JSON.stringify(zoneitem))
        })
        })
    }
   }
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Dai Nguyen Your solution did work. I changed it slightly to just match ```itemID``` to ```zoneItemID```. since these will always be unique. I appreciate your help. Maybe I was using to many nested filter().